# OOP, aggregation in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, performance, oop, aggregate

I have some complex objects and I don't want to implement it and have memory leaks later, so must ask :)
Is this good way of doing aggregation? Do I need and where to clean Role object from User?

```
#import "Role.h"

@interface User : NSObject {
    NSString *firstName;
    NSString *lastName;

    Role *role;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *lastName;

@property (nonatomic, retain) Role *role;
@end
#import "User.h"

@implementation User
@synthesize firstName;
@synthesize lastName;

@synthesize role;
@end

@interface Role : NSObject {
    NSInteger *roleId;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *description;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSInteger *roleId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *description;
@end
#import "Role.h"

@implementation Role
@synthesize roleId;
@synthesize title;
@synthesize description;
@end
```

Comment: So all I need is this in my User class: -(void)dealloc
{
 [super dealloc];
 [role dealloc]; 
}

Comment: Just some advice: It's a good practice to use copy-attributes for NSString-properties. And remove that NSInteger-pointer (no *).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dealloc methods need to look like the following:

For user:

```
-dealloc
{
    [firstName release];
    [lastName release];
    [role release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

For Role:

```
-dealloc
{
    [title release];
    [description release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

roleId does not need to be released because NSInteger is actually a typedef to a primitive integer type.  That also means your property declaration is wrong, it should be:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger roleId;
```

Also, NSString is immutable and it implements the copying protocol so your NSString properties should be `copy` not `retain`.  e.g.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *firstName;
```

**Edit**

As Björn points out, the interface for Role should be:

```
@interface Role : NSObject {
    NSInteger roleId;  // not a pointer
    NSString *title;
    NSString *description;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger roleId;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *description;
@end
```

Comment: Good answer -- but since NSInteger is a primitive integer type, the declaration should be `NSInteger roleId` instead.

Comment: Well spotted @Björn.  I missed that in the question.

Comment: Thanks for great explanation. And thank you for pointing me at NSString - copy, I always put retain and now I see that that is wrong.